# I am facing some error while rendering the react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So i am passing props to another component and i am using those passed prop values to return another react component
This is how i planned to work but i am not getting any component as a output

My code to take input from the user

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react';
import { CheckThala } from './CheckThala';
const InputBox = () => {
    const CheckThala = () =>{
        return <CheckThala value = {value} />;
    }
    const ValueHandel = (e) => {
        setvalue(e.target.value);
        console.log(value);
    }
    const [value , setvalue] = useState("1234567");
    return (
        <div className='WapperBox'>
        <h2>Thala for any reason</h2>
        <input type="text" id='inputText' onChange={ValueHandel}/>
        <button onClick={CheckThala}> Click me</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default InputBox;
```

My code to check the condition and return the respective component to it

```
import React from 'react'
import Thalatrue from './Thalatrue'
import Thalafalse from './Thalafalse'

export const CheckThala = ({value}) => {
    {
        if (value.length === 7){
            return <Thalatrue/>
        }
        else{
            return <Thalafalse/>
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are defining CheckThala twice.  Pass your prop to the imported component, not the one you created inside InputBox.   Don't create components inside of other components.